# Compare dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

I want to compare a date from a database that is between 2 given dates.
The column from the database is DATETIME, and I want to compare it only to the date format, not the datetime format.

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10),us_reg_date,120) >= '2000-07-05' AND CONVERT(CHAR(10),us_reg_date,120) <= '2011-11-10'
```

I get this error when I execute the SQL above:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   'us_reg_date,120) >= '2000-07-05' AND
>   CONVERT(CHAR(10),us_reg_date,120) <=
>   '2011-' at line 1

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can try below query,

```
select * from players
where 
    us_reg_date between '2000-07-05'
and
    DATE_ADD('2011-11-10',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: For people comming from google: date type in mysql comes in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 106):

That is [SQL Server syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for converting a date to a string. In MySQL you can use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract the date from a datetime:

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE DATE(us_reg_date) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10'
```

But if you want to take advantage of an index on the column `us_reg_date` you might want to try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE us_reg_date >= '2000-07-05'
  AND us_reg_date < '2011-11-10' + interval 1 day
```

Comment: I appreciate your consideration of taking advantage of the index. I think the query should not have the "+ interval 1 day" clause.

Answer (score 15):

This works:

```
select date_format(date(starttime),'%Y-%m-%d') from data
where date(starttime) >= date '2012-11-02';
```

Note the format string `%Y-%m-%d` and the format of the input date. For example `2012-11-02` instead of `12-11-2`.

Answer (score 7):

I got the answer.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column, '%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('29/01/15', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('07/10/15', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 4):

this is what it worked for me:

```
select * from table
where column
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('29/01/15', '%d/%m/%Y')
 AND STR_TO_DATE('07/10/15', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Please, note that I had to change STR_TO_DATE(column, '%d/%m/%Y') from previous solutions, as it was taking ages to load