# MYSQL search between two date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 dates in database like this:

```
from_dateTime = 2013-06-12
to_dateTime   = 2013-07-10
```

I want to search all records between `from_dateTime` and `to_dateTime`. I tried to use following code in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM users i
WHERE i.from_dateTime >= '2013-06-12' AND i.to_dateTime <= '2013-07-10'
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. Why am I getting empty result set?

**UPDATE:**

```
from_dateTime = 2013-06-11
to_dateTime   = 2013-06-12
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users i WHERE  NOW() between i.from_dateTime AND i.to_dateTime
```

`NOW()` is `2013-06-12 08:17:13` and command cant find my record too.

Comment: use "between" function

Comment: What didn't work about it?

Comment: is the date in database are in date format or string format??

Comment: What error your getting ?

Comment: @Harjeet Jadeja , i dont get error. this command could not find record between dates

Comment: @mahdipishguy there is no record then. Which record you want to be in result set?

Comment: What kind of field is from_dateTime and to_dateTime?

Comment: @Orangepill, if topic is between dates must be view and find with command

Comment: i hope this will help you....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql

Comment: @mahdipishguy your query works just fine for me given you have the correct dates in place http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea778/1/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing dates and datetimes.  Dates start at midnight.  Any time component is larger than the corresponding date.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE date(NOW()) between u.from_dateTime AND u.to_dateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users i 
WHERE cast(NOW() as date) 
      between i.from_dateTime AND i.to_dateTime
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fe74/3)**

Answer (score 1):

```
select from table_name where datetime_column >= '2013-06-11' and datetime_column <= '2013-06-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [between](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm)

```
SELECT * FROM users u where date(NOW()) between u.from_dateTime and u.to_dateTime
```