# All records within 3 month access WHERE clause on Date PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I want to do a `Quater` wise search on the records store in the database. The problem is that i don't know how to use `BETWEEN` in date. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM ACED 
         INNER JOIN RACE
         ON ACED.RACE_NO=RACE.RACE_NO

         WHERE R_DATE 
         BETWEEN 
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(R_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MON-YY') = 'JAN-14'
         AND
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(R_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MON-YY') = 'MAR-14'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql

Comment: Is R_DATE a timestamp, date, or datetime type?

Comment: R_DATE is a column name.

Comment: Yes, but what is the datatype of that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`between` works in the same fashion for dates, numbers, strings, etc - You just need to make sure you pass `date` arguments and not character arguments (which will cause the operator to do a lexicographical comparison). E.g.:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       aced
INNER JOIN race ON aced.race_no = race.race_no
WHERE      r_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-14','mm-yy') AND 
                          TO_DATE('03-14','mm-yy')
```

Comment: its saying `STR_TO_DATE` is a invalid identifier

Comment: for some reason I decided this was a MySQL question - fixed.

Comment: Okay now no errors. just showing zero results. I will fix that problem. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM ACED 
         INNER JOIN RACE
         ON ACED.RACE_NO=RACE.RACE_NO
         WHERE   
         TO_CHAR(R_DATE,'Q') = 1;
```

`Q` in format model gives you the quarter of the year. Jan to march is 1st Quarter. and so on.

Comment: what is that Q? @OracleUser

Comment: You can refresh the screen and try again. You might not see my updated answer.