# Comparing dates mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I am trying to make a calendar view. I need to check if a `$currentDateTime` is between a `startdate` and `enddate` in a mysql query.

I have tried this query, based on [Compare dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql)

```
SELECT id, startdate, enddate FROM hirings
WHERE startdate <= '$currentDateTime'
AND enddate <= '$currentDateTime'
```

where $currentDateTime is in format `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`

but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting `0 rows` returned.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: In what format is your PHP datetime? Use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: `startdate <=` should be `startdate >=`

Comment: what is the datatype of startdate and enddate in the database ? and how they are stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the default datetime format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

```
SELECT id, startdate, enddate
FROM hirings
WHERE '$currentDateTime' between startdate AND enddate
```

or if you want to use the current SQL time then you don't even need a parameter to your query

```
SELECT id, startdate, enddate
FROM hirings
WHERE NOW() between startdate AND enddate
```

Comment: I used your sql, and it worked! Thanks! I did however leave the format the same, it still works...

Answer (score 0):

change query to startdate >= instead of <=

`SELECT id, startdate, enddate FROM hirings WHERE startdate >= '$currentDateTime' AND enddate <= '$currentDateTime'`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Code-only answers are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT hr.id, hr.startdate, hr.enddate 
FROM hirings hr
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('$currentDateTime', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
between hr.startdate AND hr.enddate;
```