# Greater than date condition giving wrong values

Tags: mysql

I have wrote a query to get all records greater then a date. My query is

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`user_registered`, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM `wp_users` `a` JOIN
`wp_usermeta` `b` ON `a`.`ID`=`b`.`user_id` WHERE `b` .`meta_key` = 
'wp_capabilities' AND (DATE_FORMAT(`user_registered`, '%d-%m-%Y')> 
 '08-03-2016' );
```

Then my result contain some dates of 2014 and 2015 like

```
| 08-12-2014                                 |
| 18-06-2015                                 |
| 08-06-2015                                 |
| 21-10-2015                                 |
| 14-07-2015                                 |
| 09-11-2015
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, this kind of hack cannot use an index, so will be far slower than simply saying `WHERE user_registered > '2016-03-08'`. It's better if you can to handle the formatting of dates in the end user's locale and keep everything that happens 'behind-the-scenes' in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34058692/3603374) `STR_TO_DATE` function

Comment: @Hytool date is stored with date time fromat.

Comment: Well, you could simply do `DATE_FORMAT(`...`, '%Y-%m-%d')> 
 '2016-03-08'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT() returns a string, when it is compared with another string '08-03-2016', they are compared as string.

Therefore, you can see that the 'string' bigger than string '08-03..' are returned.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`user_registered`, '%d-%m-%Y') 
FROM `wp_users` `a` JOIN
    `wp_usermeta` `b` ON `a`.`ID`=`b`.`user_id` 
WHERE `b` .`meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND 
    DATE(`user_registered`) > STR_TO_DATE('08-03-2016', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: it giving error `ERROR 1525 (HY000): Incorrect DATE value: '08-03-2016'`

Comment: Updated. try again. @Vinie