# How to compare date on PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How to compare date on PHP MySQL?

I use below code on PHP MySQL. I want to know my code better or not for PHP MySQL rule?

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE date < '2017-06-12'";
```

Column “date” is type `date`.

Comment: Date comparison answer can be found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql

Comment: What happens with the current query? What do you mean by `php mysql rule`?