# compare two date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hotel check in & check out time is

Table data

```
   check in                   check out                room name
2018-09-17 11:00:00           2018-09-19 11:00:00      room 1
2018-09-18 11:00:00           2018-09-19 11:00:00      room 2
```

> Note : Standard Check in and Check out time : 11:00 AM

if i try for date `from 2018-09-17 11:00:00 to 2018-09-18 11:00:00` then `output for that date total booked should be 1.` room 1 is booked and room 2 should be free.

my query

```
SELECT * FROM transcationmaster WHERE checkin >= STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-17 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and  checkout  <= STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-18 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

how to do this in mysql?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql)

Comment: @Sfili_81 this query use  on single column but i want to check * check in * and *checkout*  date both. Is this work in that query.

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of that link.  This is the overlapping range problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the overlapping range problem.  To find records which overlap with your own date range, try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactionmaster
WHERE '2018-09-17 11:00:00' < checkout AND '2018-09-18 11:00:00' > checkin;
```

[image]

### Demo