# SQL - Compare DateTime to current time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, comparison

So, I have `isOnline` (boolean) and `lastTimeSeen` (DateTime) fields in my users table.

Everytime a user loads a page on my application, lastTimeSeen will be updated for him.

Then, I want to make a SQL query that will retrieve all users that have the `isOnline` column equals to 1 and where `lastTimeSeen` column is superior to 5 minutes to set `isOnline` to 0.

Though, I have no idea how to compare a DateTime with current time in order to check if the user has not been seen in the last 5 minutes.

Do I have to do that with PHP?

```
UPDATE FROM users WHERE isOnline = 1 AND lastTimeSeen => comparison to make
```

Could you guys help me with that?

Comment: Maybe the answers here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql

Comment: Maybe `lastTimeSeen >= (now() - interval 5 minutes)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
SET isOnline = 0
WHERE isOnline = 1 
AND lastTimeSeen < now() - interval 5 minute
```

Comment: I think it should be `>=`, right? Otherwise it will be > 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Though this syntax "now() - interval 5 minute" looks really weird to me. Edit : just noticed this is a substraction

Comment: @user3783243: It should be ***superior** to 5 minutes*. So  `<` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
WHERE MY_DATE_FIELD <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```